# RecordInvalid, Validation Failed for custom date validaton

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to validate if a room booking check in date is before the checkout date and after today.

When I run the code I get the Error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid on BookingsController#create
Validation failed: Check in Invalid Start Date
```

Im guessing that is the validation working, however I need the app to not crash and instead show the error to the user.

Booking Controller:

```
def create
    @booking = Booking,create(booking_params)
    current_user.bookings << @booking         ##Error is called here.
```

Booking.rb:

```
validate :val_start_before_end
validate :val_start_after_today

def val_start_before_end
    errors.add(:check_out, "Invalid Date") if check_out < check_in
end

def val_start_after_today
    errors.add(:check_in, "Invalid Start Date") if check_in < Date.today ##Error is called here
end
```

It passes the first test as i change the start date to a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you can store the initialization of a new Booking and check if is valid. If it's not, then you can return the object errors:

```
def create
  @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
  if @booking.valid?
    ...
  else
    # return errors
    @booking.errors
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a div that shows only on errors.

new.html.erb:

```
<% if @booking.errors.any? %>
  <%= tag.div class: 'alert alert-danger' do %>
    <p>
      <%= pluralize(@booking.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this form from being saved. See and correct the errors below before 
      submitting.
    </p>
    <ol>
      <% @booking.errors.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
<% end %>
```

bookings_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

  if @booking.save
    flash[:success] = "Booking saved"
    redirect_to bookings_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Also, if you put a form field in the form with the current user's ID (I generally do a hidden field), then you don't need to put `current_user.bookings << @booking` in your controller.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

Comment: Will the new div render in the booking view? Or will it render a 'new' view that the user has to go back into?

Comment: Good question. It renders the new view again (which I'm assuming is the view you're using for the creation of a booking). Try it out. Make a booking that violates one of your validations.